# Alternative to CString::Format?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, format

Is there any better alternative for doing string formatting in VC6, with syntax checking  before substitution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CString` offers the `Format` method for `printf`-style formatting, but this isn't type-safe.

For type-safe string formatting you could either use `std::stringstream` / `std::wstringstream` or the [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/index.html) library, although these both work with the C++ `std::basic_string` class template, and not the MFC `CString` class. I've used both of these successfully in VC6.

Boost Format is nice because it allows you to use `printf`-like syntax, and will throw an exception if the arguments you supply don't match the format string, whereas string formatting with C++ iostreams tends to make your code quite verbose.

Note that you can create a `CString` object from a `std::string` as follows:

```
std::string s;
CString str( s.c_str() );
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: std::string and std::stringstream are both elements of the standard library.  If you need wide-char variants, use std::basic_string<wchar_t> and std::basic_stringstream<wchar_t>.  So: yes, VC6 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [FastFormat](http://www.fastformat.org/). It has an easy syntax, and a "sink" - FastFormat terminology for the thing that receives the result of the formatting operation - for CString.

Something along the lines of:

```
int i = 1;
std::string ss = "a std string";
CString cs = "a Cstring";

CString result;

fastformat::fmt(result, "i={0}, ss={1}, cs={2}", i, ss, cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

[FormatString - smart string formatting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/FormatString.aspx)
By Ivo Beltchev

Posted on CodeProject